# Kdenlive rendering problem - white video

Tags: kdenlive, render

I'm doing some editing and I'm trying to render my video but regardless of the output format what gets rendered is just a white screen, still video with the length of my project.

I'm using 
Kdenlive
Version 19.08.2
on Ubuntu 18.04

Perhaps there is already a solution to this problem but I'm having a really hard time finding the correct wording to look up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that my video sources contained spaces in their names i.e.
"My Video.mp4". Once I removed all spaces from the filenames it started rendering normally.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with moving files outside of Kdenlive. It did find them using a recursive search, but the video was white. I have deleted them from the project and added them again. This fixed it in my case.

Comment: I  believe this was my issue. It's obviously confusing to the App if clips 'disappear'

Answer (score 0):

I use 21.08.0 sometimes when the render is still there. I've found that if restarting the program and opening the project file, Kdenlive will display a file search screen after searching for the file. The image returned to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue. A quick solution is to 'enable proxy clips'. It worked for me, at least.